# WordPress won't let me send or receive emails, how can i fix it?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, elementor, cloudways

I'm working on a website using WordPress/"Elementor Pro" and the "WP mail SMTP" plugin for email.
The problem started a few days ago:
We have a form for our clients, but once they finish filling it out and click send, they do not receive the verification email and we do not receive the completed form.
This is the error i see when i try to submit the form my self:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0FnTU.png)
Where are using Cloudways as server with "Elastic email", I've already put the configuration the Bot told me but still doesn't work. Some are telling me that it could be a plugin error, but i don't know.

Answer (score 0):

### Using Cloudways Addon

If you are using Cloudways, then you can utilize their SMTP Addon.
[image]
https://support.cloudways.com/en/articles/5130857-how-to-activate-the-custom-smtp-add-on

It wont require SMTP plugin on your site.

### Using WPSMTP Plugin

If you like to take care of the SMTP on your site then use WP SMTP plugin and configure any transactional email service as Cloudways don't allow PHP mailer so if you have WP SMTP configured to deliver email using PHP then it may not work as expected.
Make sure you are not using multiple SMTP plugin.

### How to test the Email?

Go to https://www.mail-tester.com/

Get a disposable email and try sending a test email via WP SMTP plugin.
[image]

If you receive the email successfully, check the SPAM score and fix the issues pointed by mail-tester.

The more score you get, the more chance you have to hit the inbox.